# Error in order(datastate$c) : argument 1 is not a vector

Tags: r

```
best <- function(state, outcome) {
    data = read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses="character")
    data[, 11] <- as.numeric(data[, 11])
    data[, 17] <- as.numeric(data[, 17])
    data[, 23] <- as.numeric(data[, 23])
    if (outcome == "heart attack") { 
        dataset <- data[,c(2,7,11)]
    } else if (outcome == "heart failure") {
        dataset <- data[,c(2,7,17)]
    } else if (outcome == "pneumonia") {
        dataset <- data[,c(2,7,23)]
    }
    dataset<- na.omit(dataset)
    names(dataset)<- c("a","State","c")

    datastates <- split(dataset, dataset$State)
    datastate <- datastates$state
    order.h <- order(datastate$c)

    answer <- datastate[order.h,]
    answer [1,1]
}
```

The error I am getting in my code is;
Error in order(datastate$c) : argument 1 is not a vector

I believe it is because I did not write the code before it correctly. The code show take the name of the state that I put into the function and create a data set of 3 columns in the order of the third column.

Comment: You tell us: **show us `print(datastate$c)` already**. Without the dataset, this example isn't reproducible. The elements of `datastate$c` come from the various columns selected by your `if..else` ladder.

Comment: You need to narrow your issue down to the smallest sample of code *(Minimal Reproducible Example)*. No point in posting your wall of code here without the dataset.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Error in order(datastate$c) : argument 1 is not a vector` means that `order()` doesn't know what to do with `datastate$c` because it is not a vector. I can't say for sure as you haven't provided data, but my guess is that `datastate$c` is returning `NULL`.

Your problem likely lies in the following code:

```
names(dataset)<- c("a","State","c")
datastates<- split(dataset, dataset$State)
datastate <- datastates$state
order.h <- order(datastate$c)
```

According to `?split`, "the value returned from split is a list of vectors containing the values for the groups. The components of the list are named by the levels of f". In other words, your object `datastates` no longer has the structure of a `data.frame` and your attempt to access `datastate$c` isn't working. I would run your function up till `datastates <- split(dataset, dataset$State)` and then call `str()` on `datastates` to determine its structure.