# R overlap line plots with ggplot with categorical variable on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I'm getting an error I don't understand when trying to make a basic line plot. I'm sure there is a simple fix. Here is my df (Chrom has 24 values, some numbers and some letters).

```
> df
# A tibble: 375 x 4
   Sample BasesCovered FractionOfTotal Chrom
   <chr>         <int>           <dbl> <chr>
 1 AE        169850837           0.682 1    
 2 BE        112368817           0.451 1    
 3 HE        116402736           0.468 1    
 4 C         142399396           0.572 1    
 5 AE:BE      93870879           0.377 1    
 6 AE:HE      98319854           0.395 1    
 7 AE:C      108852071           0.437 1    
 8 BE:HE      69040576           0.277 1    
 9 BE:C       72772760           0.292 1    
10 HE:C       74645628           0.300 1    
# ... with 365 more rows
```

Here is my code to make a plot based on this [line graph example](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/)

## plots

```
ggplot(df, aes(y="FractionOfTotal", X="Chrom", group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour="Sample"))

ggplot(df, aes(y="FractionOfTotal", X="Chrom")) +
 geom_line(aes(group=1))

ggplot(df, aes(y="FractionOfTotal", X="Chrom", colour="Sample")) +
  geom_line()
```

Each of these attemps throw this error:

```
Error in order(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  argument 3 is not a vector
```

I'm not sure what argument 3 is? So I tried this which didn't help:

```
> is.vector(df$Sample)
[1] TRUE
> is.vector(df$Chrom)
[1] TRUE
> is.vector(df$FractionOfTotal)
[1] TRUE
```

I tried to search the error and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247647/error-in-orderdatastatec-argument-1-is-not-a-vector) but in this case there appears to be a problem with the df which I can't see is true in my case.

I'm sure this is something simple?

Comment: Remove quotes from column names (eg: `aes(y=FractionOfTotal, x = Chrom)`).

Comment: Hi PoGibas, I've just tried this for all 3 plot examples and it still throws the same error.

Comment: Please add example of your data using `dput` function.

Comment: It should be lower case `x` inside `aes` (instead of capital `X` as in your code).

Comment: Ah that seems to have fixed it Maurits Evers! Damm typo! Many thanks!

Comment: @user3062260 Great, I had just added a post below to elaborate. That was a quick fix then;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comment above, I'm not actually sure what you're trying to plot, but the following works (note the lower case `x` inside `aes`)

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = FractionOfTotal, x = Chrom, group = 1)) +
    geom_line(aes(colour = Sample))
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "   Sample BasesCovered FractionOfTotal Chrom
 1 AE        169850837           0.682 1
 2 BE        112368817           0.451 1
 3 HE        116402736           0.468 1
 4 C         142399396           0.572 1
 5 AE:BE      93870879           0.377 1
 6 AE:HE      98319854           0.395 1
 7 AE:C      108852071           0.437 1
 8 BE:HE      69040576           0.277 1
 9 BE:C       72772760           0.292 1
10 HE:C       74645628           0.300 1    ", header = T)
```